# Why/how can model.forward() succeed both on input being mini-batch vs single item?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Why and how does this work?

When I run the forward phase on input

- being mini-batch tensor
- or alternatively being a single input item

`model.__call__()` (which AFAIK is calling forward() ) swallows that and spills out adequate output (i.e. a tensor of mini-batch of estimates or a single item of estimate)

Adopting testcode from the [Pytorch NN example](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html) shows what I mean, but I don't get it.

I would expect it to create problems and me forced to transform the single item input into a mini-batch of size 1( reshape (1,xxx)) or likewise, like I did in the code below.

( I did variations of the test to be sure it is e.g. not depending on execution order )

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import torch

# N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
# H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
#N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 10, 4, 3

# Create random Tensors to hold inputs and outputs
x = torch.randn(N, D_in)
y = torch.randn(N, D_out)

# Use the nn package to define our model as a sequence of layers. nn.Sequential
# is a Module which contains other Modules, and applies them in sequence to
# produce its output. Each Linear Module computes output from input using a
# linear function, and holds internal Tensors for its weight and bias.
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(H, D_out),
)

# The nn package also contains definitions of popular loss functions; in this
# case we will use Mean Squared Error (MSE) as our loss function.
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

learning_rate = 1e-4
for t in range(1):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted y by passing x to the model. Module objects
    # override the __call__ operator so you can call them like functions. When
    # doing so you pass a Tensor of input data to the Module and it produces
    # a Tensor of output data.
    model.eval()
    print ("###########")
    print ("x[0]",x[0])
    print ("x[0].size()", x[0].size())
    y_1pred = model(x[0])
    print ("y_1pred.size()", y_1pred.size())
    print (y_1pred)

    model.eval()
    print ("###########")
    print ("x.size()", x.size())
    y_pred = model(x)
    print ("y_pred.size()", y_pred.size())
    print ("y_pred[0]", y_pred[0])

    print ("###########")
    model.eval()
    input_item = x[0]
    batch_len1_shape = torch.Size([1,*(input_item.size())])
    batch_len1 = input_item.reshape(batch_len1_shape)
    y_pred_batch_len1 = model(batch_len1) 

    print ("input_item",input_item)
    print ("input_item.size()", input_item.size())
    print ("y_pred_batch_len1.size()", y_pred_batch_len1.size())
    print (y_1pred)

    raise Exception
```

This is the output it generates:

```
###########
x[0] tensor([-1.3901, -0.2659,  0.4352, -0.6890,  0.1098, -0.3124,  0.6419,  1.1004,
        -0.7910, -0.5389])
x[0].size() torch.Size([10])
y_1pred.size() torch.Size([3])
tensor([-0.5366, -0.4826,  0.0538], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
###########
x.size() torch.Size([64, 10])
y_pred.size() torch.Size([64, 3])
y_pred[0] tensor([-0.5366, -0.4826,  0.0538], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
###########
input_item tensor([-1.3901, -0.2659,  0.4352, -0.6890,  0.1098, -0.3124,  0.6419,  1.1004,
        -0.7910, -0.5389])
input_item.size() torch.Size([10])
y_pred_batch_len1.size() torch.Size([1, 3])
tensor([-0.5366, -0.4826,  0.0538], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs on [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.0.0/nn.html?highlight=Linear#torch.nn.Linear) state that

> Input: (N,∗,in_features) where ∗ means any number of additional dimensions

so one would naturally expect that at least two dimensions are necessary. However, if we look [under the hood](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.0.0/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear) we will see that `Linear` is implemented in terms of [`nn.functional.linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.0.0/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.linear), which [dispatches](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.0.0/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html#linear) to [`torch.addmm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.addmm) or [`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.matmul) (depending whether `bias == True`) which broadcast their argument.

So this behavior is likely a bug (or an error in documentation) and I would not depend on it working in the future, if I were you.

Comment: So now I better understand why with my own model class (derived from nn.Module) this feature "item vs batch" resulted in some errors. (the layers did not start with a linear). Thx for linking to the relevant sources.